# Angular 4+ overwrite child component's style

Tags: angular, sass, angular5

I want to force parent comp to change child comp's style without the !important modifier. My question is.. is there any way to do that? (I am beginner to angular may not the best solution.)

Here is a minimal example about the 2 comps. Child has a simple div in template :)

parent.component.scss:

```
::ng-deep .child-div{
    background-color: red;
}
```

childe.component.scss:

```
.child-div{
    width: 100rem;
    height: 100rem;
    background-color: $pink;
    color: $blue;
    line-height: 100rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Thanks for your time and answers! :)

Edit #1 ---
I tried it from the global style.scss

[image]

Comment: Did you try? `::ng-deep .child-div[_ngcontent-c1]{
    background-color: red;
}`

Comment: Yep, but does not work :(

Comment: Can you specify your element structure here?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add to your global stylesheet

```
app-root app-child .child-div {
   background-color: red;
}
```

You also have to turn off the [viewencapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) of the child component. I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/viewencapsulation-turned-off) for demonstration.

Keep in mind in this case you will always override the childs style because the app-component will always be a parent of any child component.

Comment: It did not help :( Components has a higher priority, because they are generated after the global. I made an edit with a picture about it .

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: I can use css > operator to handle the "keep in mind" part right? :)

Comment: Not sure, you might wanna try it :)

Comment: In the example you are not exactly overriding from parent component right? Its part of global css. If we write same css in app component style file it wont work.

Comment: You are overriding the child component style using the parent component selector. Yes, it won't work. That is because of shadow-dom. Since the ::deep selector has been deprecated, this is the way to go.