# How to overwrite a css from main.component.scss in a child component scss file

Tags: html, css, sass, angular6

I have a scss file for my main component of my Angular 6 Application inside which i have added a css property for an html element. I want to overwrite the css property in the scss file in a child component. I have tried putting `:host /deep/` and `!important`. Nothing works for me. I have tried changing the css property from the .ts file and it worked. I want to overwrite the same in my scss file only.

Example: 
main.component.scss

```
.global-content {
  margin-left: 12rem;
}
```

This is the main component scss file. I am trying to overwrite the same css property from my child component like this

child.component.scss

```
:host /deep/ .global-content {
  margin-left: 2rem !important;
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Please read this post about how to use encapsulation with sass in angular. 
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

And also try removing the "/" forward slash. may or may not work depending on your structure.

```
:host { 
   deep { 
      .global-content { margin-left: 2rem !important; }
   }
}
```

The above is just a guess as I can not test in here.

or you could use ng-deep css pseudo element:

```
:host ::ng-deep .global-content { margin-left: 2rem !important; }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe this?
:host(.global-content) { margin-left: 2rem !important; }

Answer (score 0):

Add Your Global Style sheet

like

```
app-root app-child .child-div {
   //add whatever css property you want to call
}
```

Ref : [You Can Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154831/angular-4-overwrite-child-components-style)